# pass string from dialog to MainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, data-transfer, qdialog

I'm trying to make a program which has MainWindow.cpp and a dialog1.cpp, I need to pass a string from QLineEdit of my dialog to a function in MainWindow.cpp.Till now I have just made a qt dialog form class and used modal approach to view the dialog.
The dialog gets input from lineedit in a myString.
Dialog.cpp

```
    void Dialog::on_buttonBox_clicked(QUrl fileUrl)
{
    QString myString = ui->lineEdit->text();
}
```

Now I have to transfer the data in myString to dnldFile function as parameter which is in MainWindow.cpp.

```
    void MainWindow::on_dnldButton_clicked()
{
    Dialog newDnld;
    newDnld.setModal(true);
    newDnld.exec();
    dnldFile();
}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Show some of your relevant code.

Comment: You can do it just like you would in any C++ code, `QString` is a well-behaved class that you can pass by value from `lineEdit->text()` to the target function.

Comment: Add a getter method to Dialog, returning ui->lineEdit->text()

Comment: Can you show some example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply declare myString as a class member and get the value by a getter method and pass it to your function:

```
QString Dialog::getString()
{
    return myString;
}
void MainWindow::on_dnldButton_clicked()
{
    //Dialog is showed via "Modal approach".
    Dialog newDnld;
    newDnld.setModal(true);
    newDnld.exec();
    dnldFile(newDnld.getString());
}
```